# GoDaddy DomainName and AWS EC2 Hosting - should be done by re-writing (A) record or by forwarding with masking?

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, domain-name, godaddy, forwarding

I have an Elastic IP `192.0.2.4` for my EC2 instance for example.

I have a GoDaddy domain name `www.example.com` for example

I want my domain name www.example.com to load pages from `http://192.0.2.4/a_sub_directory/` -- I have two queries about that.

1. The other forums I browsed through ([ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/229092) and [Quora](http://www.quora.com/If-I-bought-a-domain-name-from-Godaddy-but-plan-to-use-amazon-EC2-to-run-the-site-do-I-need-hosting-from-Godaddy/answer/Tom-Yuin)) suggest I need to re-write the A Host's @ record to the Elastic IP that's connected to my EC2 instance. What if I want the domain name `http://www.example.com` to load up my page at `http://192.0.2.4/a_sub_directory/` instead of the root directory at `http://192.0.2.4/`?
2. GoDaddy domain manager has something called "[Forwarding with Masking](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name)". Can I use that feature to load up my EC2 hosted instance from my GoDaddy domain name INSTEAD of changing any A record or anything?

Comment: You can do all sorts of things, but *why* would you want to?  Just setup the webserver on your EC2 instance to serve `www.example.com` out of whatever the *actual* docroot is.

Comment: i **DID** setup the webserver on my EC2 instance.......... I am trying to figure out how to connect my GoDaddy domain name with EC2 instances which is **ALREADY** serving my pages globally via elastic IP

Answer (score 2):

1. Your elastic IP will allow you to have `http://1.2.3.4/a_sub_directory/` which can be visited by anyone. However, `A records` are at the DNS level, they only allow you to point `example.com` into `1.2.3.4` so you'd have `http://example.com/a_sub_directory/` - but it's not possible to remove `a_sub_directory` from this using DNS alone. You need another system.
2. Yes, you can use this feature. Just forward/mask your domain onto `http://1.2.3.4/a_sub_directory/` without changing any A records and you'll be done.
3. A better solution would be to use Apache, and have `example.com` with a `DocumentRoot` of `/var/www/html/a_sub_directory/`. This way `example.com` will load everything from `a_sub_directory` but it's clean, and the user is none-the-wiser (it's what *everyone* does). You will need an `A Record` into `1.2.3.4.` This comes from [Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) which many HTTP servers (Apache, Lighttpd, etc.) deal with very well - so you have `example.net` and `example.com` both on `1.2.3.4` but with two different directories serving their content.

It is worthy to note that forwarding/masking is not "clean". You can see the page load, then the frame load inside. Any links inside the masked frame will be of the form `http://1.2.3.4/a_sub_directory/images/test.jpg` and if a user does a `Right Click > Copy Link` then they'll get a `http://1.2.3.4/a_sub_directory/...` link, not `example.com`.

Comment: by the noteworthy point you mentioned, i understand it's best to re-write the A records to point to my Elastic IP. But the problem is, the root folder of my website is in a **subdirectory** of my AWS instance. Is there anyway i can make this work?

Comment: Yes, please see the third point I added. If you are happy configuring Apache, this would be the perfect solution.